# How to get the third row from STDOUT?

Tags: bash, postgresql, kubernetes

I have a STDOUT in form of table with the following content:

```
$kubectl get postgresql

NAME                   TEAM        VERSION   PODS   VOLUME   CPU-REQUEST   MEMORY-REQUEST   AGE     STATUS
acid-minimal-cluster   acid        12        2      1Gi                                     2d16h   SyncFailed
acid-userdb            acid        12        2      5Gi      100m          100Mi            2d16h   SyncFailed
databaker-userdb       databaker   12        2      2Gi      100m          100Mi            2d16h   SyncFailed
databaker-users-db     databaker   12        2      2Gi      100m          100Mi            2d15h   Running
```

and would like to get the row with **NAME** = `*users-db` and the **STATUS** = `Running`, that means the last line.

What I am trying achieve is, to check if the database has been successfully deployed or not.

Before this coding block:

```
echo "Check if database $DB_NAME is correctly deployed"
for i in {1..3}; do
  if [ kubectl get postgresql $DB_NAME | egrep -q "$DB_NAME|Running" ] ; then
    echo "DB $DB_NAME successfully deployed"
    break
  elif [ $i -eq 3 ]; then
    echo "DB $DB_NAME not successfully deployed"
    exit 1
  fi
  sleep 3
done
```

I have to pick up the right row first.

How to write a bash script to get the corresponding row with **NAME** = `*users-db` and the **STATUS** = `Running` ?

Comment: `if [ kubectl get postgresql $DB_NAME | egrep -q "$DB_NAME|Running" ]` is wrong. Remove the square brackets, they don't run the bracketed code.

Comment: Something like `kubectl get postgresql --field-selector 'STATUS==Running' | grep '.*-userdb'`? (Not sure if `--field-selector` supports any kind of pattern matching for the names, instead of using `grep`.)

Comment: @chepner it does not work, it says:
`Error from server (BadRequest): Unable to find "acid.zalan.do/v1, Resource=postgresqls" that match label selector "", field selector "STATUS==Running": field label not supported: STATUS`

Comment: Hm, too bad. Seems like the command should be able to handle the filtering you want to do, but I don't know what the correct invocation should be.

Comment: @chepner but good point. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, could you just clarify which row do you want to get? because the title sais third row, which is `-userdb` and on the body of the question you are asking for the forth row with `-user-db` sign. Also are you trying to filter pods regardless of the first word of the name? or are you specifically targetting `databaker-users-db` ? Also, could you check the answer from @petrus4 to see if it solves your issue? otherwise let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
awk '$1~/users-db$/ && $9=="Running"'
```

`$1` < -- First field
`$9` < -- Last field
`\  \`  <-- Used for regex match

Comment: The first data row, with no entry for `CPU-REQUEST` or `MEMORY-REQUEST`, makes me leary of assuming `$9` will be the value of the `STATUS` column.

Comment: @chepner then use ```$NF``` instead of ```$9```

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl get postgresql | sed -n '/databaker-userdb/p'

kubectl get postgresql | sed -n '3p'
```

The first option is probably safer with modern datafiles which don't tend to have consistent structures, because it uses a keyword.  If you always know which line number you want, however, you can just print that.